# An issue when doing cumulative sum of an array in BigQuery Java UDF

Tags: java, google-bigquery, udf

I need to do a cumulative sum of an array in BigQuery Java UDF. For the example I give below, I'm expecting the result to be: [1,3,6,54,54]. But instead I get:

[image: result from bigquery]

Could anyone let me know what I did wrong please? I'm a Java and UDF newbie. Thanks!

```
#Standard SQL    
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
      test(a ARRAY<int64>)
      RETURNS ARRAY<int64>
      LANGUAGE js AS """
    n=a.length;
    for (var i=1;i<= n-1;i++)
    {
    a[i]+=a[i-1];
    }
    return a;
    """;
    WITH
      test AS (
      SELECT
        [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        48,
        0] AS a)
    SELECT
      test(a)
    FROM
      test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[INT64 is not officially supported with JavaScript UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#supported-external-udf-data-types) at this time since there is no 64-bit integer type. Instead, you should use FLOAT64 for numeric values, e.g.:

```
#StandardSQL    
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  test(a ARRAY<float64>)
  RETURNS ARRAY<float64>
  LANGUAGE js AS """
n=a.length;
for (var i=1;i<= n-1;i++)
{
a[i]+=a[i-1];
}
return a;
""";
WITH
  test AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY<FLOAT64>[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    48,
    0] AS a)
SELECT
  test(a)
FROM
  test
```

Comment: Thanks! But strangely enough, it can be worked out for a[i]-=a[i-1] or a[i]*=a[i-1] or a[i]/=a[i-1] but just not for sum ... This is really weird .. Anyway, Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It's because the int64s are represented as JavaScript strings in order to preserve precision (though since int64s aren't officially supported, this is subject to change). Sticking with FLOAT64 is probably the best option for now.